# Way to ignore used unit to make code completion faster

Tags: delphi

My code completion is OK but when I use a 3rd party unit it become editor become very slow. Is their a way for code completion to completely ignore a unit during code completion?

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, 

  CoreDCore, // i want to use this but should be ignored by code completion

  ActiveX;
```

Comment: There is no way to tell Code Completion to ignore specific units.

Comment: This is sad. Just one unit and made editor very slow. I'm hoping embarcadero would consider this in their future release

Comment: CoreDCore is not a standard Delphi unit distributed as part of the Delphi installation. How is Embarcadero supposed to deal with why someone else's unit slows down Code Completion? Talk to the author of that unit and get them to figure out what it's doing wrong.

Comment: Can you link to that unit so others of us can reproduce this behaviour? After all the culprit could also be about your environment (CPU, RAM, platform...) and a unit that overly publishes way too many things.

Comment: @KenWhite Embarcadero is supposed to make the IDE work efficiently with any valid source code regardless whether it's their own or 3rd party code.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/255-ide-hangs-on-code-completion-find-declaration-parameters-tooltip/) old thread on Delphi-PRAXIS making a full rebuild of the project could improve performance of Code Insight.

Comment: @dummzeuch: But they can't guarantee with absolute certainty that it will, because they can't possibly test against 100% of the code that will ever be written. Who knows what's in that unit that the OP is complaining about? Do you?

Comment: We don't even know which code insight we are discussing here. The old one or the new LSP one. And we don't know what is in this unit. I totally agree that code insight should be resilient and not drag the IDE down. But if you want practical help you need to supply more details.